# Where is Daniel Trigg from Ancestry Source?

Tags: immigration, ancestry.com, 17th-century, virginia

This is taken from a record page on from Ancestry for [Daniel Trigg](https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=7486&h=4099895&ssrc=pt&tid=23767283&pid=26446295673&usePUB=true) from their online database *U.S. and Canada, Passenger and Immigration Lists Index, 1500s-1900s*, which is derived from Filby:

> Original data: Filby, P. William, ed. Passenger and Immigration Lists Index, 1500s-1900s. Farmington Hills, MI, USA: Gale Research, 2012.

```
Name:   Daniel Trigg
Arrival Year:   1672
Arrival Place:  Virginia
Source Publication Code:    6221
Primary Immigrant:  Trigg, Daniel
Annotation: Date and place where land was patented and record was created listing those transported/imported. Only the names of those to be transported were indexed. Abstracted from Patent books 6 through 8, from the Land Office records located at the Virginia State
Source Bibliography:    NUGENT, NELL MARION. Cavaliers and Pioneers: Abstracts of Virginia Land Patents and Grants. Vol. 2: 1666-1695. Indexed by Claudia B. Grundman. Richmond, VA: Virginia State Library, 1977. 609p.
Page:   113
```

I've found the [book Filby cites on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/cavalierspioneer00nuge#page/112), but on page 113 I find no mention of any Daniel or Trigg.  I look at the prior and following pages, but found nothing there either.  There is also no mention in the index of any Daniel Trigg.

How can I locate the record referred to by Ancestry.com for Daniel Trigg?

Note that the Ancestry source refers to volume 2, but there appears to never have been a volume 2 created.

Comment: That appears to be Volume 1. The citation refers to volume 2

Comment: Please consider that visitors to this site might not have an active subscription to Ancestry. Your original link to the record page only said "here" which tells people nothing about what you were looking at. I had to decipher the database ID to see that you were consulting Ancestry's online version of Filby.  When our questions are transparent about what we've consulted, it allows other people to consult other versions of our sources on other sites. I think it is good to link to other sites, but we shouldn't force people to go offsite in order to read and understand our questions.

Comment: @sempaiscuba It appears the volume 2 is a source of confusion.  See the 2* review of Filby's book on [this entry for volume 1 at the Internnet Archive](https://archive.org/details/cavalierspioneer00nuge) that complains in part: `This book was published in 1934 when Nugent first received support for publishing the series, which was withdrawn by the donor just as the second volume was going to press.`

Comment: Hmm. "_there appears to never have been a volume 2 created._". Interestingly, [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=cgcSAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=trigg) would beg to differ.

Comment: @WilliamKF I have corrected your obscure "this page" link in your comment to make the link more transparent.  '

Comment: @WilliamKF if Volume 2 was never published, why are there entries for Volume 2 in WorldCat?  Better yet -- if Volume 2 was never published, how did Filby come to index it?

Comment: @semipascuba Indeed, on Google Books, even when the volume number isn't included in the title or in the 'about the book' entry, we can still see the image of the title page which clearly says Volume Two.  It's not a great image, but I can still read it. (And below that, there are later volumes, with the volume numbers clearly visible on the title pages which are displayed in lieu of cover artwork.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find *Cavaliers and Pioneers : Vol. 2 1666-1695 Abstracts of Virginia Land Patents* in a library near you by looking on [Worldcat.org](https://www.worldcat.org/title/cavaliers-and-pioneers-vol-2-1666-1695-abstracts-of-virginia-land-patents/oclc/733747258&referer=brief_results).

After that, you can use research guides such as the FamilySearch Wiki's article on [Virginia Land and Property](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Virginia_Land_and_Property) to help you find and evaluate the original records.

Using the advice in the FamilySearch wiki, you can search for Daniel in the [Basic](http://lva1.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/F/?func=file&file_name=find-b-clas30&local_base=CLAS30) or [Advanced](http://lva-linux-temp.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com:8991/F/S7NEBNJ4793VFG652AEPB64K4T1XKT3YUFF78LJC4LTN96C611-26542?func=file&file_name=find-d-clas30&local_base=CLAS30) Search of the Land Office Grants at the Library of Virginia.

> A Tiff viewer that supports Group IV compression is required to view the images.

The records are also available to view chronologically, and information about the records is available on this page: [About the Virginia Land Office Patents and Grants/Northern Neck Grant and Surveys](http://www.lva.virginia.gov/public/guides/opac/lonnabout.htm?_ga=2.232859677.2021694370.1516477217-34462678.1516477217).

Note too the advice given in [Biographical Research at the Library of Virginia
The Seventeenth and Eighteenth Centuries (Research Notes Number 16)](http://www.lva.virginia.gov/public/guides/rn16_biographical.htm)

> Catherine Drinker Bowen offered sage advice to researchers in her
>   Adventures of a Biographer (1946). "In libraries it is not well to
>   hurry," she wrote. "To the research worker, haste is fatal. The books
>   have been where they are for a long time; they reveal themselves
>   slowly, at their own pace." Those who undertake biographical research
>   at the Library of Virginia—whether for a scholarly book, journal
>   article, or family history—must take the time to examine a wide range
>   of materials in a variety of formats.

Comment: Used copies can also be found on sites like AbeBooks, For [example](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=11223126856&searchurl=bi%3D0%26ds%3D30%26bx%3Doff%26sortby%3D17%26kn%3DAbstracts%2Bof%2BVirginia%2BLand%2BPatents%2Band%2BGrants%2B1666%26recentlyadded%3Dall&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title14)

Comment: Or via a meta-search site like Bookfinder.com, which includes search results from ABEbooks.

Comment: Also, if you go to WorldCat and scroll down the page, there are links to ABE *and* to other booksellers.